# jQuery toggle input when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, input, toggle

I'm trying to build something like wordpress options section. When you click the checkbox you can toggle the display of the corresponding `<input type="text">` field, I want to do this all in one function so I don't have tons of different functions so what would be the best way to toggle the corresponding input with the checkbox, I made a quick jsFiddle but when I use my checkbox it toggles all the inputs because I'm selecting all of them obviously, so what would be a better solution using like `this` or something so toggle the corresponding field, thanks in advance, http://jsfiddle.net/MEC9n/

**HTML**

```
<div class="options">
    <input type="checkbox" name="title"><label>Title</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="author"><label>Author</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category"><label>Category</label>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title:">
        <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Author:">
        <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category:">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            $('input[type="text"]').toggle();
        });
    });
```

Comment: You should incorporate your code into the question.

Comment: [jQuery: Toggle input text using checkbox](http://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/jquery-toggle-input-text-using-checkbox)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should help

### Basic Solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var item = $(this).attr('name');
        $('input[name="'+item+'"][type="text"]').toggle();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaTq3/)

### Maybe better?

If you really want to make it efficient, extend jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.fn.rmCorrespondingText = function () {
        var context = $(this);
        context.bind('click', function () {
            var item = context.attr('name');
            $('input[name="' + item + '"][type="text"]').toggle();
        });
    };

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').rmCorrespondingText();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaTq3/3/)

Comment: Awesome thanks for your time! Probably the cleanest version thanks!

Comment: @MitchellLayzell try the new one, I just updated. Now you don't even need to do the `.click()`

Answer (score 2):

Check for the corresponding attribute `name`:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
     var name = this.name; //<---------------------------this is faster
     $('.container').find('[name="'+name+'"]').toggle();
   });
});
```

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MEC9n/3/)

Comment: Wow, awesome thanks you so much, and thank you everyone for the quick replys!

Answer (score 1):

Use type and name together for mapping with respective textbox like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
           $('input[type="text"][name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').toggle();
    });
});
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/G5tN7/

I hope, it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I added values to the inputs and then used the value names to assign class names and use that to toggle the inputs. 
This is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('.' + value).toggle();
    });
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="options">
    <input type="checkbox" name="title" value="title"><label>Title</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="author" value="author"><label>Author</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="author" name="category"><label>Category</label>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
        <input class="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title:">
        <input type="text" class="author" name="author" placeholder="Author:">
        <input type="text" class="category" name="category" placeholder="Category:">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

And the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/MEC9n/1/